# How can I read a text file from Azure blob storage directly without downloading it to a local file(using python)?

Tags: python, azure, azure-blob-storage

How can i reads a text blob in Azure without downloading it? I am able to download the file and then read it but, i prefer it to be read without downloading.

```
print("\nList blobs in the container")
generator = block_blob_service.list_blobs(container_name)                  
for blob1 in generator:
    print("\t Blob name: " + blob.name)
```

Is there any operation in 'blob1' object, which would allow me to read the text file directly.(like blob1.read or blob1.text or something like this)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Azure Blob - Read using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48881228/azure-blob-read-using-python)

Comment: No. That is not the answer i am looking for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`get_blob_to_text`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-python/blob/master/azure-storage-blob/azure/storage/blob/baseblobservice.py#L2218) method.

```
block_blob_service = BlockBlobService(account_name='myaccount', account_key='mykey')

blob = block_blob_service.get_blob_to_text('mycontainer', 'myblockblob')
print(blob.content)
```

Comment: Do you know how would one go about reading a pdf ? I don't see a get_blob_to_pdf sort of method

Answer (score -1):

You can read the content of txt file in the blob and assign the content to a variable without downloading the file with [BlobServiceClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.blobserviceclient?view=azure-dotnet):

```
blob_service = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(<connection string>)
container_client = blob_service.get_container_client(<container name>)
file_content = container_client.get_blob_client(<blob file name>).download_blob().readall()
```

You can find instruction of configuring Azure Storage connection string [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-configure-connection-string)

Comment: It seems that by calling `download_blob()` you in fact download the blob, which is not OPs intention.